# Can the user disable sounds for push notifications locally?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I'm using APNs, I have two questions around the use of sounds or buzzing.

1. Can we just have the device buzz, instead of playing a sound?
2. Can the user disable sounds via their local system settings for my app? If not, I'd have to build a remote service to let them opt out of sounds for push notifications, and store that option on my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about just buzzing, but yes, the user can disable sounds for push notifications from your app. In the Notification settings for your app there's a switch called "Sounds", just under "Badge App Icon".

[image: Screenshot of Riposte push notification prefs]